# onClick and className not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Onclick does not work in this component. This is the first time I have ever encountered this error, I have tried going through the code, I have bound all functions to `this` and yet `onClick` method is not working at all. Any className that I add to the `div` inside the `Col` is not being applied too.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { safariTypes }  from '../../data/safariTypes';
import uuid from 'uuid/v1';
import '../../App.css';
const ThePeople = './Media/thePeople.jpeg';
const BoraBora = './Media/bora.jpg';
const Aerial = './Media/balloon.jpg';
const Family = './Media/family_small.jpg';
const Honeymoons = './Media/honeymoon_small.jpg';
const Wildlife = './Media/wildlife.jpg';


    class Highlights extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
        this.returnSafariItemsHighlights = this.returnSafariItemsHighlights.bind(this)
        this.show = this.show.bind(this)
    }
show = () => {


     console.log("hey");

 }

    returnSafariItemsHighlights(){

        var Feature = null

        var arr = []
        if(safariTypes){
            safariTypes.slice(0,6).map((item, key) => {
                if(item === 'Aerial e.g Hot air ballons'){
                    Feature = Aerial
                } else if(item === 'Wildlife') {
                    Feature = Wildlife
                } else if(item === 'Family and Holiday') {
                    Feature = Family
                } else if(item === 'Beach Holidays') {
                    Feature = BoraBora
                } else if(item === 'Culture and History') {
                    Feature = ThePeople
                } else if(item === 'Honeymoons'){
                    Feature = Honeymoons
                } 


                arr.push(

                <Col  xs={24} sm={12} md={12} lg={8} xl={8}  key={uuid()} onClick={this.show} >
                <div 
                className="bounceAnimation"  
                style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + Feature + ')', 
                backgroundSize: 'cover', 
                backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                height: '40vh',
                paddingTop: '28vh',
                paddingLeft: '20px',
                paddingRight: '20px'
              }}>

                <div  style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4)", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "25px",padding: "5px", fontFamily: "Lobster", color: "green"}}>

                #{item}

                </div>
                </div>

                </Col>


                )
            })
        }
        return arr
    }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>{this.returnSafariItemsHighlights()}</div>


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your console say, give us the error

Comment: There is nothing on the console.

Comment: where does this variable come from `if(safariTypes){`?

Comment: It is imported, that does not have an issue, the data is present. It is just an array of some words.

Comment: Can you show all your code please? `Col` is coming from a library presumably, and may not accept `onClick` events.

Comment: I tried it on the `div` too but it is also not working.

Comment: If the div is inside the col that might be why.

Comment: @AhadisoftTechnologies could be wrong, due to this being hard to read, but the code itself seems totally fine, replace `<Col>` with a `<div>` as codecubed.io suggested and report back on what the outcome is. Also, does this get rendered at all? As in do you see the anything in the browser? That is the only thing that might be the problem, good catch codecubed.io.

Comment: `Col` doesn't take `onClick` prop

Comment: I replaced the `Col` with `div` and it works. Good catch. Why is it not working with `Col` though?

Comment: @AhadisoftTechnologies because that's just how antd seem to have defined it like that. Instead you wrap the col a div then use that. You can see the props accepted by col here: https://ant.design/components/grid/

Comment: @AhadisoftTechnologies my bad `Col` should work with `onClick` see https://repl.it/repls/ScentedFrostyMinimalsystem

Comment: I wrapped the `Col` in a `div` but it still not working. I have to remove the `Col` for it to work.

Comment: your code works, I didn't change anything see https://repl.it/repls/ScentedFrostyMinimalsystem

Comment: If the items are rendered in a row(left to right) it does not work, if the items are rendered in a single column (top to bottom) it works. Maybe it is due to the styling. I tried to create rows with bootsrap and as soon as I float the Items left or right it stops working.

Answer (score -2):

it seems Col does not accept onClick prop, why don't you move `onClick={this.show}` to the div inside Col as follows

```
<Col
  xs={24} sm={12} md={12} lg={8} xl={8}  key={uuid()} >
  <div 
    onClick={this.show}
    className="bounceAnimation"  
    style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + Feature + ')', ...}}
  >
     ...
  </div>
</Col>
```

I think I found a performance issue, every time the component renders it will call `returnSafariItemsHighlights`, there you populate an array of components with a key prop which is generated every time you call the function, when react reconciles it will find different keys in that case child components will not be reused.

Comment: please see the example above in the comments `Col` does accept `onClick`